# Using HTML tags in Angular Scope Data

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

In my Angular app, I have some data that I need to include html tags in and I'm having some trouble making sure it gets escaped.

```
 $scope.groups = [
    {
      'name': 'min',
      'item': '<h1>This is some awsome H1</h1><ul><li>yup></li></ul>',
    },
     {
      'name': 'min',
      'item': '<h1>This is some awsome H1</h1><ul><li>yup></li></ul>',
    },
     {
      'name': 'min',
      'item': '<h1>This is some awsome H1</h1><ul><li>yup></li></ul>',
    },
     {
      'name': 'min',
      'item': '<h1>This is some awsome H1</h1><ul><li>yup></li></ul>',
    }
  ];
```

And here's my html

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <li>{{group.name}}</li>
  <li>{{group.item}}</li>
</div>
```

I tried just including some of angular's `ng-sanitize`, but I've only seen examples where its a single object, and not an array.

[See here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e1zoOrEVwqdIDPujMpPC?p=preview)

I try to add `ng-bind-html="groups"` to the main `div` but my data comes out as `[object Object]`.

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `ng-bind-html="group.item"` on the second `<li>`?

Comment: YES! Thanks for the quick replay. Want to answer it and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @javaCity seems to have put that in an answer already; I'll restrain myself from adding duplicate answers ;)

Comment: @mingos I have deleted my answer. You can go ahead and post yours :)

Comment: @javaCity you didn't need to do it :)

Comment: @mingos someone else posted the answer! haha

Comment: Ha, didn't expect three answers! Thanks all of you

Comment: @javaCity I had already written my answer when I noticed the "new answer was posted" banner. Plus, since you made an effort to create the plunker, I didn't want your work to go to waste :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ngBindHtml` directive accepts a string containing HTML and should be used directly on the tag wherein that HTML string should be rendered. Instead of using it on the container, use it directly on the second `<li>` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <li>{{group.name}}</li>
    <li ng-bind-html="group.item"></li>
</div>
```

@javaCoin created a Plunker illustrating this; let's not let it go to waste and paste it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PFaxHqpyQvWqln5ABHRc?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

ng-bind-html is on the specific item you want the code in.

So, your example becomes:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <li>{{group.name}}</li>
  <li ng-bind-html="group.item"></li>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CO5WUCgBnOEJrVoKKrEE?p=preview shows a quick and dirty example of this.